# pip3 says "resolve pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.3.1"

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

On OSX 10.7.5, I'm trying to use the `pip3` command to install packages to python3. When I try, I get this error message:

```
zak$ pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/setuptools-1.0-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2793, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/setuptools-1.0-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 673, in require
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/setuptools-1.0-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 580, in resolve
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 1.4.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==1.3.1'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1567, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1534, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/setuptools-1.0-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2797, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/setuptools-1.0-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.3.1
```

It looks like `setuptools` is demanding an old version of pip (I have 1.4.1 installed), but why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you installed anything, or is this using Homebrew's `pip` out of the box? I wouldn't be _that_ surprised about the latter, as setuptools 1.0 is pretty new, and has some backward incompatibilities, and Homebrew's recipe may not have been completely updated yet… But it would be nice to rule out incompatible leftovers from earlier installations (e.g., you had distribute, and then installed a recent setuptools without uninstalling distribute first).

Comment: Also, do you have a `PYTHONPATH`? And if you `print(sys.path)` from within Python, are any of those directories shared with any other Python installation on your machine?

Comment: After a bit of fooling around, I was able to trigger this by installing a Python.org 3.3 (putting `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin` on the PATH instead of linking to `/usr/local/bin`), installing pip 1.3.1 and its minimum dependencies, then installing a Homebrew 3.3 with its pip 1.4.1. I ended up with `/usr/local/bin/pip3` being the 1.3.1 python.org script, but pointing to `/usr/local/bin/python3.3`, which is the Homebrew version, which finds pip 1.4.1 in `/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages`.

Comment: And the obvious fix for that worked: uninstall the other Python 3.3, unlink the brew one, `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.3`, re-link the brew one. Unless you need two Python 3.3 versions, or you're absolutely sure this doesn't apply to you, try it and see.

Comment: Which is the brew install and which is the imposter?

Comment: Anything actually installed by brew will be a symlink to something in `/usr/local/Cellar` (specifically, in `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/`, but you're fine just checking for Cellar). Or, more simply, you can `brew unlink python3` and it will go away (and `brew link python3` to get it back). The problem is that if you've done something like `pip3 install ipython`, you may end up with a `/usr/local/bin/ipython3` that's a symlink to something in `/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages` whether it was installed by the Brew python or the other.

Comment: Anyway, do you know that you have another Python 3.3, and, if so, do you know how you installed it? The first place to look is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`. Does it exist? If so, what's under its `Versions` subdirectory? That's where Python.org and many third-party binary installers go. Also, do you have an `/opt/local` or `/sw`? (Actually, `brew doctor` should diagnose those two, so run it.)

Comment: `Anyway, do you know that you have another Python 3.3, and, if so, do you know how you installed it?` I do. Inside `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions` are 3.3 and 2.7. I don't remember how I installed them.

Comment: I have an `/opt` but it's empty. I have no `/sw`.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/zakdances/6314916) is the output of `brew doctor`

Comment: OK, if you don't mind breaking those third-party Python 2.7 and 3.3 installations (it won't affect your Apple-installed 2.7, which you don't want to break), you can just trash `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`, `/usr/local/lib/python*`, and `/usr/local/share/python*`. Also, however you've added the `share` directory to your PATH (likely an `export PATH=…` line in ~/.profile), undo that, along with any similar lines for other Python-related paths. Then fire up a new Terminal shell, `echo $PATH` to make sure whatever you removed is actually gone, and `brew  uninstall python3`.

Comment: That should clean out _everything_ non-Apple-Python-related that matters. Check `brew doctor` again to make sure there are no more warnings about Python. (The MacFUSE stuff is fine; you might want to do the `brew prune` suggestion, but it doesn't matter here.) Then `brew install python3` and cross your fingers, and you should end up with a working 3.3 with a working pip and everything.

Comment: I don't have a `~/.profile`. Did you mean `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: It could be in either of those; `.bash_profile` is more likely, but check them both.

Comment: Thanks Andy. You're quite the mysterious Unix wizard. Not sure how I can give you a green check because your answers are in the comments...

Comment: I can write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you have two different Python 3.3 installations, and a shared site-packages directory.* And the tool you run as `pip3` is from pip 1.3.1, but the modules it uses to do its work come from pip 1.4.1.

The easiest way to solve this, unless you actually need both Python 3.3 installations, is to get rid of both of them completely, then reinstall the one you want.

The following should work (possibly with `sudo` for some of the commands—or using Finder and letting it tell you whether you need to authenticate).

Note that this will *also* partially or completely remove any other third-party Python versions (e.g., a python.org 2.7.5), which I don't think is a problem for you, but could be for future readers.

You might want to make a list of all installed packages before uninstalling anything. (I usually do this in the hackiest way possible: fire up `ipython`, and let it tab-complete an import statement…)

Finally, some of these details will be different for any future readers with similar problems, but the basic ideas should be the same.

- `brew uninstall python3`
- `rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`
- `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python*`
- `rm -rf /usr/local/share/python*`
- Find where in `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.profile` or elsewhere) you add the Python paths to your PATH. You may have `/usr/local/share/python3` and/or something inside the `Python.framework` or `Cellar/python3`. Scrap all that you find.
- Fire up a new shell in Terminal.app.
- `brew doctor`, and fix anything that it complains about that seems potentially relevant (the non-Homebrew MacFUSE stuff is fine as-is; the `brew prune` suggestion is probably worth doing, but doesn't matter here), and run it again to make sure.
- `brew install python3`.
- `pip3` to reinstall any packages you deleted that you need again.

---

* Details:

- Homebrew Python 3.3 is installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/`, with various things symlinked into `/usr/local/bin` and its siblings, and possibly into `/Library` somewhere.
- Another Python 3.3, possibly from the python.org installer, is installed in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/`, with various things possibly symlinked into `/usr/local/bin` or otherwise added to your PATH.
- Both probably include `/usr/local/lib/python3.3` in their site-packages search.

Answer (score 0):

After running

`pip install --upgrade setuptools`

I was able to fix it. But this may not be true for everyone for I am still learning Python.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was caused by a broken Python installation, I was able to fix it by reinstalling Python with Homebrew.

```
brew reinstall python3
```